# Assign Id / name attribute for uniquely identifying drawn polygon

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

How do I assign a unique id and name to a drawn polygon, and hover those details on the polygon with the help of `Openlayers`?

Comment: you need to show some effort of your own, as in.. show some code you tried that did not work. maybe follow a tutorial, read example code and the documentation.

Comment: @hoijui I have worked on this. http://jsfiddle.net/Sanju5390/dkg8zLfn/ Can you help me on this.

Comment: include code in your question please (not just linked), as this way it will not become invalid when your link does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you finish drawing, use [`ol.feature.setId()`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.Feature.html#setId) like:

```
draw.on('drawend', function(evt){
    var feature = evt.feature;
    feature.setId(some_uniq_id);

    //do you want to set other properties?
    feature.setProperties({
        name: 'some_name'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.This is what I was expecting to do.